# PhpStorm terminal shortcuts: switch tab, return to editor, etc. (Mac)

Tags: macos, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

On opening PhpStorm's Terminal Tool Window, I would expect to be able to run commands like Ctrl + Tab to switch terminal tabs, or Cmd + 1 to open the Project Tool Window, but my keyboard is stuck inside the Terminal.

Is there a way to release the keyboard from the Terminal so that I can return to regular commands? (Without using Option + F12 to hide the Terminal Tool Window.)

Comment: Alt+Left/Right is to jump between terminal tabs (that's on Windows; On Mac it's Ctrl+Left/Right -- just verify that wit your Keymap in Preferences)

Comment: Project View tool window shortcut does not work indeed .. but the one for Favorites or Structure works just fine... Therefore I may suggest to jump to structure via `Alt+2` (`Cmd+2` on Mac) and then just `Esc` to get into Editor). See if you can record macro, assign custom shortcut to it and see if it will work for you.

Comment: Other than that: 1) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-116221 2) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-119666

Comment: @LazyOne Heh well the Cmd+2 trick certainly works! Thank you. I've tried every combination of Modifier + Left/Right (Ctrl, Cmd, Shift, Option) but it won't switch Terminal tabs in PhpStorm 9. I also can't find the option under Preferences > Keymap.

Comment: Look for "Main Menu | Window | Editor Tabs | Select Next/Previous Tab" actions in Keymap. (P.S. Keymap has search field where you can enter "tab" and see all actions that have it in their names/descriptions. P.P.S. Button next to it allows to search by shortcuts)

Comment: @LazyOne Found it! For me it was Cmd + Shift + [ for previous and ] for next. Thanks! I would absolutely accept your answer if you posted it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. Switching between Terminal tabs can be done using the same shortcut as Editor tabs: <kbd>Alt+Left/Right</kbd> on Windows using Default keymap (on Mac it would be <kbd>Cmd + Shift + [</kbd> and <kbd>Cmd + Shift + ]</kbd> (or whatever you have got there for `Main Menu | Window | Editor Tabs | Select Next/Previous Tab` -- you can verify/change it in your `Preferences | Keymap`)).
2. Project View tool window shortcut (<kbd>Alt+1</kbd> on Windows or <kbd>Cmd+1</kbd> on Mac) does not work indeed if used in Terminal.. but shortcuts for Favorites or Structure tool windows still work just fine.

   Therefore I may suggest to jump to Structure via <kbd>Alt+7</kbd> (<kbd>Cmd+7</kbd> on Mac) first and then just use <kbd>Esc</kbd> to get into Editor). P.S. See if recording macro with such sequence will work for you (you can assign custom shortcut to it).

Comment: To jump to the last editor tab from the terminal it works for me (on MacOS in phpStorm 2017.3) to do <kbd>Alt+1</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd><kbd>Esc</kbd>.  But when I try to record a macro with that sequence the resulting macro only contains <kbd>Alt+1</kbd>. So <kbd>Esc</kbd> must not be valid in macros.  I haven't found any way to escape <kbd>Esc</kbd> when creating a macro...any work around for getting <kbd>Esc</kbd> into the macro?

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest simply adding another keyboard shortcut for accessing the terminal. E.g. ⌘0

F12 is the default shortcut for Mac and Linux OS.

This shortcut will toggle terminal focus. The default F12 shortcut for Mac (dunno about Windows) will not.

You may need to restart PhpStorm to hijack ⌘0 or whatever you choose.

Answer (score 0):

You can access terminal by `Alt` + `F12` on Windows

Answer (score 0):

PHPStorm and other products of Jet-brains are configurable to your liking. you don't need to learn new keyboard shortcut jus configure the as you prefer.
For example for me i use PHPStorm VS code and Sublime text editor for my coding daily.
So it is good to have same key-map on all of your IDES/Text editors
i am on mac  and i use these key-map for all of the mentioned above

```
  Command + !    => toggle Explore tab
  Command + ~.   => toggle Termina tab
  Command + 2.   => toggle console tab
```

So to configure any keyboard of your choice this on PHPStorm (macOs)

1. Hit Command + , and you will be on PHPStorm Preferences
2. Go to Key-map if you happen to know the current working shortcut on your PHPStorm
    then on you right side after the search box there is a keyboard hit it and press the current working key let say by default toggling terminal is option + F12 (please note for some keyboard you need to add function key(fn) that will make it be option/alt + fn + F12)
3. Hope you will see terminal with keyboard shortcut at the right side, then two finger click/ right click hope you will have a popup menu to add new keyboard shortcut or remove the existing one.
4. Add your preferred keyboard shortcut first before removing the existing on (why ? since as soon as you remove the keyboard and you firstly got there via that keyboard shortcut the result will refresh and the thing will disappear from the view)
5. Note some of the new shortcut you prefer will be already in use that should not scare you away. just remove that and remap with a new binding later which you find useful for you.
6. Apply and ok then you are good to go !